# How to bring an element outside of its parent element using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a markup that looks like this:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Uno</li>
    <li>Dos</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Basically, what I want to do is bring the `<ul>` outside of its parent . How can I do this using CSS if possible? Thanks.

Comment: Which element, Outside...to where?

Comment: You want to change the DOM? Impossible with css.

Comment: What CSS have you tried?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You're talking about DOM manipulation here, this is outside the boundries of CSS

Comment: Other than positioning this is not possible but it's still not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
div{ position: relative; }
ul{ position: absolute; top: 100%; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zuremvwh/

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much!